# OS doesn’t see newly installed SSD (SATA)

Tags: fedora, partition, hard-disk, gparted, dmesg

I had broken HDD in my laptop for quite a while. Recently I’ve installed Fedora 32 on my second drive, I didn’t checkmark that broken drive during installation and everything was fine. Today I’ve replaced it with new SSD but my installation can’t see it so I booted into live, got into gparted, created partition table(gpt) and one primary partition with /ext4 file system on it. It didn’t help tho. I’ve googled it for quite a bit and the only solution I saw was changing SATA mode into AHCI but I already do use this mode. I’ve noticed something strange in my dmesg that I can’t explain, it was there since installation and I thought it was related to broken HDD but apparently it’s the same case for that new drive.

```
[ 1.063487] ata5.00: FORCE: horkage modified (disable)
[ 1.063490] ata5.00: unsupported device, disabling
[ 1.063492] ata5.00: disabled
```

Comment: Try removing the drive and cleaning its contacts with pure alcohol or something.

Comment: But both BIOS and live usb see it, I can do it but I feel like it doesn't make sense. Wouldn't it be completely invisible if the problem was on the physical connection site of things?

Comment: If you're absolutely sure you can access it from LiveCD (not just access but read/write data from/to it), it means you're looking at some sort of a serious kernel regression which probably warrants a bug report at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/

Comment: Have you updated SSD firmware to latest available. Many, even new system need updates. Also update UEFI firmware.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it once again. I'm able to write (as a root) and read from disk in liveCD session - disk is in read only mode for normal user, just saying cause maybe it matters. @ArtemS.Tashkinov

Comment: @oldfred My uefi was already updated once in the past, my main drive is SSD M.2 and it always worked fine. I don't know about SSD firmware, it's a SAMSUNG V-NAND SSD 860 EVO SATA 6Gb/s and I hoped I don't need any special firmware to run it especially cause I don't have Windows installed. If there is a way to do it on Linux I'll be glad to try.

Comment: you can use smartmontools for reading the  firmware version. `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdx` for x you have to adapt it to your situation.  Here are iso's for firmware upgrade if it is really required.  https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/  be carefull which you choose. Maybe someone other can tell your the right Version.

Comment: @nobody Here's my `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdx`:
https://pastebin.com/x6JE5LcN